# Possible Empty statement error in a loop

Tags: c#, loops

This is my first loop assignment, so I am struggling to find the error, but the code looks like this:

```
  //Loop
        for (yearDisp == startYr; yearDisp <= endYr; yearDisp++); <-EMPTY STATEMENT ERROR
        {
            listBoxDisp.Items.Add("Year:" + yearDisp.ToString());
            yearDisp = yearDisp + 1;
```

I might be putting the whole thing together wrong.. I need to create something like this:
User enters two years (ex: 1988 and 2022) and when I hit the "GO" button, the loop needs to display each year in the listbox starting with 1988, and 1999, 2000, etc all the way to 2022. Then it needs to stop.

Where am I going wrong, and why it that semicolon creating a "possible empty statement error?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Get rid of that semicolon you pointed out.  Semicolon marks the end of a statement... and you don't want your for loop to end there, otherwise it's empty.  That's why you get that error.
2. `yearDisp == startYr` should be `yearDisp = startYr`.  It's an assignment not an equality check.
3. Add a curly brace at the end of your for loop.
4. I am not sure if it's by design, but you're iterating your `yearDisp` twice.  Once by `yearDisp++` and second time by `yearDisp = yearDisp + 1`.  If you only mean to do it once, get rid of one of them.

   ```
   for (yearDisp = startYr; yearDisp <= endYr; yearDisp++)
   {
       listBoxDisp.Items.Add("Year:" + yearDisp.ToString());
       //yearDisp = yearDisp + 1; <-- may be a design error, do you need this one?
   }
   ```

Comment: Did as you said, then ran it, and got a build error: "Type or namespace definition, or end of file expected." Looking at my braces now...

Comment: @user3335698 That error would usually be caused by too few or too many curly braces.

Comment: yes! I found the missing brace, ran it. Seems to function. Testing again.

Comment: @user3335698 Check my edit (comment #4) regarding your iteration through years.  You're doing it twice per pass.

Comment: It works! Thank you, now I have to figure out how to get the checkboxes and Mod division to work within the loop! I am an "A" student, but I work full time, and live on my own.. I may ask silly questions but people like you really help when I've looked at the same thing for an hour and can't find the silly mistake. Thank you!

Comment: yes, I noticed that when I ran it and it displayed every two years instead of every year lol thanks!

Comment: @user3335698 I know how you feel.  I'm a 4.0 student myself, with a full time job and family.  Glad I could help you, though.  Good luck in your studies!